# Display turned off black after suspend

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux

On my Acer Aspire One725 Netbook, where I have installed ArchLinux, i have the problem that *sometimes* the screen is black after suspending the system.

I have testet, that I can access the computer via ssh The only problem is that the screen is not working.

I have tried the command `xset dpms force on` which didn't work. The screeen stays black.

It's not only gnome desktop manager that does not work, I also cannot switch to a terminal with (Ctrl-Alt-F2).

I guess the problem could be something have to do with the graphic card driver which seems to be unloaded on suspend and can maybe not be loaded after resuming.

I am not sure which log files I could read to find the problem.

Update: I tried starting the xServer using `sudo startx`, which gives the following error message:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
^Cxinit: unexpected signal 2
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Comment: From your thoughts, do you think it is more hardware related than software?

Comment: No i think its software

Comment: I am not sure on this but I have had some desktop systems where they lack the hardware to send a signal to the monitor on resuming a suspension. I am just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: So you think if I use kde, or fluxbox or anything else, the problem might dissapear?

Comment: I guess I would try it just to rule that out. Sorry it isn't really a concrete answer. Just something I experienced before.

Comment: What kernel do you run?

Comment: whatever kernel is default in archlinux for x86_64